# CATransform3DTranslate with zero tz not actually happening?

Tags: macos, core-animation, calayer

I have a CALayer that I need to translate, rotate, and translate back. I tried only translating it, just as a test:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, boxCenter.x - layerCenter.x, boxCenter.y - layerCenter.y, 0);
layer.transform = transform;
```

but it didn't move. Then I tried:

```
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, -angle, .0, .0, 1.0);
```

and that worked fine. So then I tried:

```
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, boxCenter.x - layerCenter.x, boxCenter.y - layerCenter.y, -1);
```

which is the same as the first one, with the difference that tz is now -1 instead of 0. Using that, the layer actually moved. Then putting the translation and the rotation worked, and then also translating back worked, with tz 0.

So what I want to know is, why isn't the first translation working?